# HTML Margin Problems

Tags: html, css, margin

The problem is essentially the bar of light green at the top of the page. I would like to get rid of that. I'm not sure whether that's because of margins or something else. I know that my background color is light green, but for some reason the h1 is too far down on the page.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Condensed' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <title>Portfolio</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div align="center" class="main-title"><h1>Portfolio</h1></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.main-title {
    font-size: 1.25em;
    font-family: "Ubuntu Condensed";
    background-color: rgb(34, 147, 0);
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    background: rgba(176, 255, 173, 0.52);
    margin: 0;
}
```

I've created a JSFiddle demonstrating my problem here: https://jsfiddle.net/r2vf5qe5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following in CSS will solve your problem.

```
h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Roger is correct! <h1> defaults to have margins on top and bottom. Try right clicking an element on the screen and clicking Inspect Element. In browser tools are great for markup debugging

Comment: @TheAustralianBirdEatingLouse Where did this solution fall short? Provide feedback to clarify your problem.

Comment: This did not get rid of the green border that I specified was the issue. EDIT: I see, you added the margin to h1 not .main-title. Thank you, this fixed the issue.

Comment: @TheAustralianBirdEatingLouse The light green bar should have disappeared after adding this CSS. If you don't want the dark green background color, you do not need to add background-color: rgb(34, 147, 0); in CSS

Answer (score 1):

You forget the default h1 margin add this code and it will work

```
h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

To remove the green background use this code https://jsfiddle.net/r2vf5qe5/7/

Answer (score 0):

Go to Page Properties and set top margin to 0 (Appearance HTML), because default top margin value is 1px.

```
<body topmargin="0">
```